# Redirect to login with user credentials after signup?

Tags: http, go

I have a link */signup*, if new user come and signup, I want it to **redirect to */login* with user credentials**, and there I want to perform login operation which is running fine and redirects the user to the dashboard.

The point at which I am stuck is I unable to redirect it to login with user credentials.

To store session I am using this package: [gorilla/sessions](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions)

Comment: For HTTP server I am using go lang build in net/http package.

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, 2 things can happen:

1. Either you let new users to sign up and then you redirect them to a
   login page where they have to type their credentials, or
2. You log people in right after they create a new account on the sign-up page.

Sounds to me that you want to do something like 2., but are having trouble with implementation.

I'm not sure how you do that with Gorilla Session API, but every authenticated page must have some code to look up a session cookie and determine if a given request is authenticated or not, so probably you want to create a session with `UserID` after a sign up and then redirect to your default page (a dashboard maybe?). Ideally, that session cookie would be encrypted.